# Stop infinite loop using GUI in bash

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

I created a bash script with infinite loop using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1289029).I want a GUI (with one or two clicks) to stop the infinite loop whenever I want. How can I do this?

Edit to clarify more about GUI (my preference) -

It should be something like gnome shell extensions provides options in drop down menu.Something like this

[image]

Comment: A GUI solution? Just click the close button for the terminal emulator window it's running in. I suppose that's not quite the kind of GUI solution you're looking for, so it might help if you could edit your original question to be more specific about how you want this to work, and why hitting ctrl-c or closing the terminal window doesn't meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This creates a XMessage window with a button and runs the loop, which keeps checking for the existence of a file given by *filename* variable. When one clicks the button, the file is created and then the loop ends.

```
gui(){
    xmessage "Click to stop loop" -buttons Stop:7
    if [ "$?" -eq 7 ]; then
        touch "$filename"
    fi
}

filename='/tmp/loopandgui'
gui &

while true; do
    sleep 0.1

    if [ -f "$filename" ]; then
        rm "$filename"
        break
    fi
done
```

Note that killing the window won't stop the loop, you need to press the XMessage 'Stop' button. If you want to stop the loop even if XMessage is killed by any means, simply remove the if condition from *gui()*:

```
gui(){
    xmessage "Click to stop loop" -buttons Stop:7
    touch "$filename"
}
```